# forward/redirect taxonomy archive of term to a page with same name

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, redirect

I have a page called "cars" with child pages for each individual car

eg (site.com/cars/ferrari)

I have created a taxonomy called 'vehicle' where each term has a car that matches the child page.

(site.com/vehicle/ferrari)

When I tag posts and custom post types with this taxonomy, I would like the link to forward to the car page instead of showing an archive page.

Is there an easy way to do this? Possibly via rewrite?

Comment: Just FYI I know it's possible to do this manually via .htaccess but I was wondering if I could do this automatically for each new page and taxonomy I add... ?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would not recommend breaking the taxonomy archives - what if someone wants to browse all posts tagged "ferrari"?

You're better off using the page URL in the first place:

```
if ( $tags = get_the_terms( $post, 'vehicle' ) ) {
    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
        if ( $_page = get_page_by_path( "cars/$tag->slug" ) )
            printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', get_permalink( $_page ), get_the_title( $_page ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably should have mentioned I'm using the Genesis framework, I'm using a specific meta filter function to add the taxonomy to each CPT and posts so it's trickier for me to add a page URL to the template in the method you described above. On the page 'ferrari' I plan to have a list of the posts and CPTs connected to the car in 3 individual lists (no pagination) so I don't think I will require taxonomy archives...